# My diploma does not have a signature on it

Tags: europe, certification

Context: I completed a doctoral degree in Italy at the end of last year (2022). I am now preparing to apply for a research position in France, and one of the required documents is a certification of equivalence for my degree. The latter requires me to present the final degree in the original language.

I requested copies of my PhD certificate in Italian and English; these were not free, I had to pay 16 euro of stamp duty on each and a further 16 euros for the request. In spite of requesting on several occasions that I be provided with paper versions (which I even offered to pick up in person) the administrative staff of the Doctoral School insisted that since CoViD, emailed PDF documents are standard and so they refused that request.

I have now received the "PDF certificates" (which appear to me more like 'diploma supplements', but that's a separate concern), and was surprised to find no obvious mark to certify that these are official documents; in particular, no signature. At the end of (the English version of) the document is written (I have omitted some identifying details),

> Revenue fee virtually paid - Authorization of the [regional body + date].
>
> [Town , date]
>
> The head officer, [name]
>
> The data of this certification are extracted from the automated information system of this institution.
> Signature is omitted according to item 3, comma 2 of the Legislative Decree 12/02/1993 n. 39.

The lack of signature was concerning to me. After doing some research, I discovered [here](https://yousign.com/it-it/blog/firma-autografa-sostituita-a-mezzo-stampa) that the quoted law justifying the omission of the signature was revoked in 2016, that such omissions are now only acceptable for "mass-mailing third parties" and that the unsigned version "carries no legal value". **EDIT**: I should have checked the claims of this source directly. Indeed, they are mistaken about which part of the law in question was revoked (see [here](https://www.normattiva.it/uri-res/N2Ls?urn:nir:stato:decreto.legislativo:1993-12-12;39%7Eart3)). I have edited the questions below accordingly.

I am following up with the university to try and get some answers, but my question for you is: is the absence of a signature a problem, as far as "officialness" of the document goes? **Does it actually matter?** Will future employers accept this document as evidence of my degree anyway, even without an electronic signature of any kind? In case it's relevant, I previously obtained a signed confirmation letter which I have been using in applications up to this point (and which I *did not* have to pay for).

Comment: The link you post is a for-profit software company that offers an alternative e-signature system, I would not necessarily trust anything they say in reference to the validity of *other* signatures.

Comment: Good point. Checked and edited accordingly.

Comment: Poor word choice on my part. I do not have an "original". Not only was one not automatically issued to me, but I had to go through a bureaucratic procedure to obtain it (whence the question). I would say I find this surprising, but after 3 years in Italy I know this to be typical...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no answer here. No one can say how "future employers" will respond.

However, the "failure" here, if any, isn't yours but due to some institutional bottleneck or other flaw. These sorts of things can normally be explained to employers. There are so many systems of certification around the world that employers just have to cope.

Unless there are other reasons for someone to suspect fraud, there is little fear that you would be disadvantaged. You can always point to the department that awarded the degree and/or your advisor, who will probably be happy enough to verify that you've properly been awarded the degree.

If a system is so bureaucratic that it can't accept this and insists (insists) on such a formality, then you may not want to work there in any case.